# Xcode Simulator not rendering images correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app runs perfectly on a physical iOS device, but when I run it in the simulator several images don't render correctly. Some images are rendering as expected but the others have a black area covering the majority of the image. Any idea what could be causing this?

These are my methods for:

**UIImage retrieval:**

(`ShopItem.swift`):

`self.image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: imageName)`

**UITableViewCell outlet:**

(`ShopItemTableViewCell.swift`):

`@IBOutlet weak var itemImageView: UIImageView!`

**Image assignment in UITableViewCell:**

(`ShopViewController.swift`):

`cell.itemImageView.image = shopItem.itemImage`

**Note:**
I've reproduced this issue on every simulated device variant I've tried and I've been unable to reproduce for every physical device I've tried

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's a simulator issue. Please check on other devices as well.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina it's worked on every physical device I've tried and failed for every simulated device I've tried

Comment: @Sneak sorry I didn't include any code but I didn't think it would be super relevant since I've only experienced it on simulated devices. I just updated my post with some relevant snippets, let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: Hmm. It is hard to figure out without more details. It seems you have the image in your ASSETS folder and you are loading it with imageNamed method(?) Is it always the same area turning black or is it different on every load? Do you always get the exact same images that turns black or is it completely random? What happens if you reload your tableView, simply calling reloadData for example after 2 second delay or something after loading your images? Have you printed out the image.size and see if it returns an actual size? What backgroundColor is your UImageView, black? If yes, change to red?

Comment: What resolution are the images you're using? and are you downloading them?

Comment: @GastonGonzalez your question got me thinking and it turns out that the resolution of those two broken images was substantially higher than the others. Reducing it to <800pixels resolved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broken images in the original post had a substantially higher resolution than those that rendered correctly. It also seems like the amount of black covering the image increased proportionally with image size. Here are the sizes of the original images:

Peas: 1440 x 960

Eggs: 2400 x 1936

Milk: 534  x 431

**Reducing these sizes to <1000 pixels fixed the issue.**